# my python code is scraping the same page (i am changing the page number)

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import csv
import lxml
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
from itertools import zip_longest
carssss = 0
page_num = 1
all_page = 100
x = False

        #print(f"page num :{page_num}")
for c in range(0,18000):
    if page_num != all_page:
        #print(all_lists)
        urls = []
        urls_list = []
        stocks_list = []
        names_list = []
        miles_list = []
        prices_list = []
        fueltype_list = []
        tran_list = []
        engine_list = []
        all_lists = [stocks_list, names_list, miles_list, prices_list, fueltype_list, tran_list, engine_list, urls_list]
        exoprted = zip_longest(*all_lists)
        car_num = 0
        website = f"https://www.cars.com/shopping/results/?dealer_id=&keyword=&list_price_max=&list_price_min=&makes[]=&maximum_distance=all&mileage_max=&no_accidents=true&page={page_num}&page_size=100&sort=best_match_desc&stock_type=used&year_max=&year_min=&zip="
        a = r.get(website).content
        s = b(a, "lxml")
        cards = s.find_all("div", class_="vehicle-card")
        cardsnum = 0
        for card in cards:
            url = card.find("a").get("href")
            finished_url = "https://www.cars.com/" + url
            urls.append(finished_url)
            cardsnum += 1
            # print(cardsnum)
        for one in urls:
            car_url = r.get(one).content
            car_soup = b(car_url, "lxml")
            gear = car_soup.find("dt", string="Transmission")
            tran = gear.find_next_sibling("dd").get_text()
            stock = car_soup.find("p", {"class": "new-used"}).text
            name = car_soup.find("h1", {"class": "listing-title"}).text
            miless = car_soup.find("dt", string="Mileage")
            milesss = miless.find_next_sibling("dd").get_text().strip(" mi.")
            oneengine = car_soup.find("dt", string="Engine")
            twoengine = oneengine.find_next_sibling("dd").get_text()
            onefuel = car_soup.find("dt", string="Fuel type")
            twofuel = onefuel.find_next_sibling("dd").get_text()
            price = car_soup.find("span", {"class": "primary-price"}).text.strip("$")

            urls_list.append(one)
            stocks_list.append(stock)
            names_list.append(name)
            miles_list.append(milesss)
            prices_list.append(price)
            fueltype_list.append(twofuel)
            tran_list.append(tran)
            engine_list.append(twoengine)
            carssss += 1
            print(f"Done Adding {carssss} Car")
            car_num += 1
        with  open(r"C:\Users\khale\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\car\cars33.csv", "a") as myfile:
            write = csv.writer(myfile)
            write.writerows(exoprted)
        if car_num == cardsnum:
            page_num += 1
            car_num = 0
            print(page_num)
```

I wanted to scrape cars from cars.com
the problem is  i get the same cars . idk where is the problem  !
page_num is changing the pparameter of the link
can any one help in this ? ? ?**
it was a def with a (global page num) and the problem was still there i tried debugging but did not get the error i tried to scrape a 100 cars age and it worked but if there is alot of pages it does not work proberly (write more details ...)

Comment: HInt number one: format your code better. THen you might be able to see what's wrong quicker. It's barely readable when it's a block like this, not to mention lack of function usage. Editing it to be cleaner will make it more likely to get answers, also.

Comment: `if car_num == cardsnum:` is this ever true? If not, then `page_num` will never increment.